# Do Elements not start from 0?

Tags: python, list, slice, element

I'm a noob, learning via Datacamp (which is really annoying and nitpicky... I could've sworn elements started from 0, counting the first element in the list as 0???? This is the problem.

"Create downstairs again, as the first 6 elements of areas. This time, simplify the slicing by omitting the begin index.
Create upstairs again, as the last 4 elements of areas. This time, simplify the slicing by omitting the end index.

I answered with

```
# Create the areas list
areas = ["hallway", 11.25, "kitchen", 18.0, "living room", 20.0, "bedroom", 10.75, "bathroom", 9.50]

# Alternative slicing to create downstairs
downstairs = areas[:-4]

# Alternative slicing to create upstairs
upstairs = areas[5:]
```

****edited to include areas as I did answer with "areas"***

Obviously this is wrong... but I could've sworn I just went through previous questions correctly..... starting with 0... as a rep of the first element... is this different when slicing? Thank you, if you have any resources for better study I would like to understand the syntax of this language better to become more intuitive with it.

Comment: If you want to slice a list, you should put the list in front of the square bracket such as `downstairs = areas[:-4]`

Comment: Hm, your `downstairs` contains last `4` elements and your `upstairs` contains elements from 5th to last. Check https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists. Actually https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html is good learning resource.

Comment: _I could've sworn elements started from 0, counting the first element in the list as 0_ Yes, this is correct.  What results are you getting that make you think this isn't true?

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova秀 ah yes, i did answer with areas. I accidentally copied the previous incorrect response in the shell but this is still incorrect.

Comment: @JohnGordon I think i'm just getting confused by the fact that they start at zero but you still count the first element as 1. Kind of like Algebra distribution with the "invisible" 1.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg Ah I was thinking the negative counting also meant you counted backwards as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python slice function does start with 0 as the default starting index, however the end is EXCLUSIVE, meaning it does not include the element at the end of the slice.

```
slice([start], stop[, step])

list[:2]    # Elements 0 and 1, stopping at 2, or the first two elements
list[2:]    # Everything except the first two elements
```

Comment: thank you!! the exclusivity clause is important to remember

Answer (score 0):

This is what the instructions are saying.

The downstairs is the first 6 elements of the list `areas`.  You can simplify the slicing by leaving the first index blank.

```
downstairs = areas[:7]
```

Upstairs is the last 4 elements of the list `areas`.  You can simplify the slice by leaving the last index blank.

```
upstairs = areas[7:]

#or

upstairs = areas[-4:]
```

And to answer your question... Yes indexing starts at `0`